# How to poison Simoc with a low Intellect and Resolve build in Pillars of Eternity?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I have a rogue build with rather low Intellect and Resolve, base values are 12 and 9.

When trying to poison Simoc, there is a huge stat check for both Intellect and Resolve. I need to get both those stats to 19/20.

How can I boost my rogue to those stats?

I already have an amulet for +2 Intellect (Unwavering Resolve) and a ring for +2 Resolve (Serel's Ring). I guess I have to find +3 items, but where?

Also, is there an inn room that will boost those too stats as well?

And are there consumables than I can eat before talking to Simoc that also add a boost?

I assume that I will have to boost my stats for up to +7 points for intellect and almost +11 points for resolve. Is this even possible to achieve this kind of boost in the game and if so: how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, a few things. First of all, you don't *have* to take one of those two stat-gated options. If you're not able to successfully con Simoc into drinking the poison, the final quest outcome is going to be pretty similar, even if you're straight up with him.

Second of all, you don't need *both* Intellect and Resolve. Just one or the other.

Finally, 20 Resolve starting from 9 is, quite frankly completely out of reach. You can only have one each of a buff from an item (+2 generally - +3's are very rare, and higher is nonexistent), a Buff from food (maxes out at +2), and a buff from resting at an Inn (maxes out at +2 for all stats with *one* exception).

Luckily for you, the one exception for Inn rests is for Intellect and it's a doozy. In the **Brackenbury** district of **Defiance Bay**, you'll find the **Charred Barrel**, an inn. Among their room offerings is the **Noble's Stay**, which grants a whopping +4 to Intellect. Combine that with your +2 Int item, and the +2 Int from a cartable **Fish Dish**, and you're at 20 Int.